# Query opportunities with open activities

Tags: soql, opportunity, tasks, event, childrelationship

I would like to be able to query all opportunities that have open events. So far, I know how to do it with SOQL + Apex, but is there a way to do it just with SOQL?

I'm looking for something like this :

```
SELECT Id, Name,
  (SELECT Id, Subject FROM Tasks),
  (SELECT Id, Subject FROM Events)
FROM Opportunity
WHERE IsClosed = false 
AND StageName != 'Ganada'
AND StageName != 'Perdida'
AND LastModifiedDate <= LAST_N_DAYS:30
AND Id IN (SELECT WhatId FROM Tasks WHERE isClosed = false)
```

The problem is that I'm getting:

> sObject type 'Tasks' is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Activities are strange in many ways, and I forgot they are not allowed in a `Left Inner Join`. The way I would get around this is to create a rollup summary via **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)**. Then your query would look something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM Opportunity
WHERE ...
AND Open_Task_Count__c > 0
```

---

You have two different kinds of join on the `Task` table in your query:

1. A [`Left Outer Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Outer_Join)
   This sub-query adds a collection of child records to the `SELECT` clause.
2. A [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join)
   This sub-query adds a filter to your `WHERE` clause, restricting which parents are returned.

This first type of join uses the `ChildRelationship` whose relationship name is `Tasks`. Because of that, you query `FROM Tasks`. However in the second join you join the table directly, so you need to query `FROM Task`.

```
SELECT Name, (SELECT Subject FROM Tasks)
                                  ^^^^^
                                  Left Outer Join uses Child Relationship Name
FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN (SELECT WhatId FROM Task)
                                                 ^^^^
                                                 Left Inner Join uses SObject Name
```

Comment: I didn't know that, thanks! Nonetheless, that isn't allowed either: Entity 'Task' is not supported for semi join inner selects.

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano Ah, well activities are strange and I guess it's not surprising. Looks like you can't do it in just one query, but this answer should clarify how the syntax works. You might consider using [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) to create a `Lookup Rollup Summary` and dump it into an `Opportunity` field called `Open_Task_Count__c`.

Comment: Aw, pity. Tbh, one part of me kinda knew it wasn't going to be posible. Great answer and thanks!